# CiviCRM Programmer/Developer Job Description

Tags: civicrm-home

Does anyone have a good job description for a CiviCRM Programmer/Developer for an open position posting?

Thanks so much!

Dina

Comment: Dina - how did you go with this?

Answer (score 2):

AGH just posted a job for a junior developer. https://aghstrategies.com/content/civicrm-developer